# Invalid column name 'database_id'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sp-blitzfirst

I loaded the stored procedure into `master` and ran:

```
dbo.sp_BlitzFirst @ExpertMode = 1
```

I got:

> ```
> Setting up configuration variables
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> Invalid column name 'database_id'.
> Now starting diagnostic analysis
> Capturing first pass of wait stats, perfmon counters, file stats
> Beginning investigatory queries
> Finished running investigatory queries
> Waiting to match @Seconds parameter
> Capturing second pass of wait stats, perfmon counters, file stats
> Analyzing changes between first and second passes of DMVs
> Analysis finished, outputting results
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> Invalid column name 'database_id'.
> ```

kit version: SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit-20161210

Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition (64-bit) version 10.50.6000.34

Comment: For support, head over here: firstresponderkit.org there's a fix for that issue already

Comment: @sp_blitzErik - you should add that as an answer, with good formatting and maybe a direct link.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I cann't find it

Comment: Try to execute: `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the two stored procedures that need to be updated.

[sp_BlitzWho.sql](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_BlitzWho.sql) and

[sp_BlitzFirst.sql](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_BlitzFirst.sql)